# Process stream elements by intervals elements

Tags: scala, stream, akka-stream

I have a question related to Akka Streams.
[Here is how my stream looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/be1cy.jpg).
I have a stream of objects and I have used groupBy to separate them by categories, however, I need a counter for each category to calculate statistics for downside component which will display the amount of each element in each category in interval of 30 elements. I am able to calculate the total amount per each group, but I need to calculate for every 30 elements passing to the sink.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand the problem correctly, you can use throttle() method

```
.throttle(elements = 30, 500.millisecond, maximumBurst = 30, ThrottleMode.shaping)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, it does not work as I wish. After throttle, I have zipwithIndex and each index exceeds 30.